# Line break in the caption of subfigure

Tags: floats, captions

I would like to add a line break in the caption of a `subfigure`:

```
\begin{figure}
  \subfigure[a long line]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{figures/cells_time.eps}
  }
\end{figure}
```

So I want to add a line break at a specific position inside `a long line`, does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Perhaps you should start with using a modern package like »[subcaption](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption)« and not an obsolete one like »[subfigure](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure)«.

Comment: Use a \parbox inside the caption.

Answer (score 8):

Lines break automatically; if you want to force a line break, use

```
\protect\\
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\subfigure[A long line\protect\\ and another]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{example-image}%
}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that `subfigure` has been obsolete for several years. Use its successor `subfig` or the more modern and powerful `subcaption`.

Comment: This gives me a different error: `The most probable cause is an omitted \item command in a list-making
environment. It is also caused by forgetting the argument of a
thebibliography environment.`
Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @xuhdev No, sorry.

Comment: @SoftTimur .I think you could accept this answer. Or is something still unclear?